# Determine if Excel cell has conditional formating colours using Vb.net with late binding

Tags: vb.net

Using the code below I am able to detect the interior colour of a cell in Excel with a VB.net application which uses late binding. The issue is that if the cell has a conditional formatting I am unable to detect the change of interior colour as applied by the conditional format using this code

```
  Dim x = objSheets.range("J" & RowCount).Interior.ColorIndex
```

Is it possible to determine the interior colour if it is as a result of a conditional format? How would I do that please?

Thank you

Comment: After further reaserch I came across this:   Unfortunately, the Color and ColorIndex properties of a Range don't return the color of a cell that is displayed if Conditional formatting is applied to the cell.  Nor does it allow you to determine whether a conditional format is currently in effect for a cell. Unless someone has figured out how to do this I will have to write the code replicates the conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I came across this: Unfortunately, the Color and ColorIndex properties of a Range don't return the color of a cell that is displayed if Conditional formatting is applied to the cell. Nor does it allow you to determine whether a conditional format is currently in effect for a cell. Unless someone has figured out how to do this I will have to write the code replicates the conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

you have to instantiate a FormatCondition object and do the following

```
FormatCondition format =(FormatCondition)( targetSheet.get_Range("D1:E10",
                Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,
                "=$D1=$E1", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing));

            format.Font.Bold = true;
            format.Font.Color = 0x000000FF;
```

Detail: 
http://www.techques.com/question/1-10240132/Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel-with-C

Comment: The thing is I don't want to change or apply it I just need to know if it exists